# How to download large files with Cordova

Tags: cordova, xmlhttprequest, large-files

I need to download a large file ( 160GB ) using my Cordova application. Previously, I used file transfer plugin. As it was discontinued, I started to use XMLHttpRequest. It works fine for smaller files, but it crashes for the big one.

Simplified code is:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.addEventListener("loadend", function (evt) {
    console.log("1");
});

req.addEventListener("error", function (evt) {
    console.log("2");
});

req.addEventListener("abort", function (evt) {
    console.log("3");
});

req.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
    console.log("4");
});

console.log("5");

try {
    req.open("GET", url, true);
    req.responseType = "blob";
    req.send(null);
}
catch (e) {
    console.log("6");
};
```

Console output is only "5" for the large file.

Answer (score 0):

Installing the plugin https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download solves this problem. However, the plugin is outdated and in its original form no longer works for Android, see [Cordova plugin background download fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75323016/cordova-plugin-background-download-fails). The modification is needed for its correct function is described in the linked question.

Comment: Hello everyone, I made these changes, but I can't download, what could I be doing wrong?