# Cordova plugin background download fails

Tags: android, file, cordova, download

I need to download huge file ( 160GB ) using my Cordova application. As file-transfer plugin was deprecated and suggested XMLHTTPRequest usage fails for huge failes, I downloaded cordova-plugin-background-download from https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download. It works great for any iOS device, but it always fails on Android 13 with error

```
Unsupported path /storage/emulated/0/ ......
```

The error is when a temporary file is being crated. I assume, the problem is with this code:

```
this.setTempFileUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(),
                Uri.parse(targetFileUri).getLastPathSegment() + "." + System.currentTimeMillis())).toString());
```

where

```
android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
```

returns invalid path.

Is there a workaround, how to make the plugin working on Android 13? I use the sample code from the plugin homepage on Github.

Answer (score 0):

Line 114 of the src/android/BackgroundDownload.java file needs to be modified for proper functionality from

```
this.setTempFileUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath(),
Uri.parse(targetFileUri).getLastPathSegment() + "." + System.currentTimeMillis())).toString());
```

to

```
this.setTempFileUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(android.os.Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),
Uri.parse(targetFileUri).getLastPathSegment() + "." + System.currentTimeMillis())).toString());
```